# Extract input parameter name from lambda expression

Tags: linq, expression-trees, linq-to-nhibernate, dynamic-linq

I am working with [system.linq.dynamic.core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) 
and nhibernate linq. Now I want to pass two dynamic linq expression to a method. One for the parent table and one for a joined child list. 
The input parameter for both expressions are random, so an expression could be

"x => x.Name == \"Wick\" "

Or

" k => k.FirstName = \"John\" "

Now I know that with dynamic linq you could parse the string expressions to a LambdaExpression.

If I want to create a join there has to be an alias for the joined table. So from the expression I would like to extract the 'x' or the 'k'. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LambdaExpression` has [a `Parameters` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.parameters), which you can use to access information about lambda's parameters. In your case, that could be something like:

```
string GetParameterName(LambdaExpression expression) => expression.Parameters.Single().Name;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Hmmm.. used the ParseLambda method of dynamic linq and it deletes my input parameter... Any chance to let it stay in there?